# Accuracy vs. simplicity as criteria to select explanatory variables

Tags: classification, logistic, predictive-models, model-selection

I want to create a binary model which predicts whether someone has improved his state. I am testing possible variables as explanatory variables in order to make some recommendations. Now my binary model is quite weak, AUC is around 0.6 and there are hardly any cases predicted above 0.5 in the test set.

Now I could simply improve my model by including the previous state which is highly correlated with improvement, but for me this is too obvious. It might 'kick out' other explanatory (more actionable) variables.

So now I am faced with this question of whether to go for accuracy or simpler/actionable model.

What do you recommend?

Comment: maybe a duplicate of [Is it problematic if one predictor in a set accounts for almost all the prediction?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/is-it-problematic-if-one-predictor-in-a-set-accounts-for-almost-all-the-predicti/10348#10348) ?

Comment: btw, are you THE [Dirk Nachbar](http://www.kaggle.com/users/926/dirk-nachbar) ?

Comment: It seems that you are not a newb. So what is concerning you ? What is your goal ? If you want to maximize accuracy no matter what, go for it (as Michael said). If you are looking for insights what _might_ cause improvement, in the sense that experts can use the information to implement new methods for grade improvement, calculate predictor importance _additionally_. Calculating the importance conditional on state predictor might lead to new insights. Finally, it might be that the important predictors are missing, e.g. social factors.

Comment: In summary, the problem of selecting a method often is caused by not knowing what you actually want to achieve. Any comment or clarification on all this ?

Comment: yes I am THE Dirk Nachbar

Comment: aahh ... I have seen you on analyticbridge and kaggle ... nice to meet you here, we definitively need for machine leaners on stats.SE. Welcome ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use whatever are the best predictors.  If the previous state is available and makes practical sense to use in the model I see no reason to leave it out.

Comment: We have included the previous state now as some other predictors were affected by its omission.