# Predictive features with high presence in one class

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, feature-selection

I am doing a logistic regression to predict the outcome of a binary variable, say whether a journal paper gets accepted or not. The independent variable or predictors are all the phrases used in these papers - (unigrams, bigrams, trigrams). One of these phrases has a skewed presence in the 'accepted' class. Including this phrase gives me a classifier with a very high accuracy (more than 90%), while removing this phrase results in accuracy dropping to about 70%.

My more general (naive) machine learning question is:

- Is it advisable to remove such skewed features when doing classification?
- How do you such handle features which are intending to predict only one class?
- Is there a method to check skewed presence for every feature and then decide whether to keep it in the model or not?

Comment: I'm surprised to see such a jump in accuracy. How many elements do you have in your training set, and do you compute the accuracy over a testing set that does not include any elements of the training set?

Comment: related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/is-it-problematic-if-one-predictor-in-a-set-accounts-for-almost-all-the-predicti. Btw, what's the phrase (just curious) ?

Answer (score 0):

- Is it advisable to remove such skewed features when doing
  classification?

  - In general, no. In various specific cases - yes. (If you hand engineered features, or used something very specific for example). Sometimes a strong feature is just that. (While in other cases it can be overfitting). 
    What's the phrase? It might be "Accepted" or "published" for example :).
- How do you such handle features which are intending to predict only
  one class?

  - Be VERY careful with your "negative set", assuming you're using discriminative classification. (And not 1 class or unsupervised methods). 
    How large and "random"/diverse is your data? (Sources, fields, journals, types? )
    Are oyu looking at the final text in the journal or the author submission? (See my question on how whether the feature is something like "accepted", "published", etc' ).
- Is there a method to check skewed presence for every feature and then
  decide whether to keep it in the model or not?

  - Best way would be Chi square (plenty of inbuilt methods. eg, sci kit learn), or Mutual Information (entropy, etc'. Maybe mrmr?), or P. correlation.